# OpenProcess не видит процессы

Tags: delphi, winapi

Делаю примерно так:

```
EnumProcesses(@prcs, sizeof(prcs), cP);
ShowMessage(IntToStr(cP));
for i := 0 to cP div 4 - 1 do
begin
  hP := OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS ,false, prcs[i]);
  if hP <> 0 then ShowMessage(IntToStr(hP));
end;
```

P.S. На самом деле код немного длинней, но тут суть отражена. и именно в таком коде поведение тоже что и описано ниже. Итоги запуска из среды и без разные немного.

В случае запуска из среды студии - первое сообщение 176, далее следует куча сообщений (список совпадает с диспетчером задач)

В случае запуска через экзешник (пробовал запускать от админа) первое сообщение 176, далее всего 2 сообщения, проверял что он видит - `C:\WINDOWS\system32\svchost.exe` (оба) и более ничего. В чем может быть проблема?

P.P.S. В Delphi 7 код срабатывает на ура (как бы не запускал, хоть от гостя, антивирусы - отсутствуют)

Comment: Полистал апи, понял ошибку, но решения пока не нашел, как указать привелегии отладочного открытия(отладочного состояния своему процессу Оо?)?

Comment: PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS - сильнО!